# How to prevent annoying Preview in El Capitan from showing thumbnails?

Tags: preview, macos

I never used thumbnails when opening PDFs, but El Capitan decided I have to see them.

[image]

And there is no option to disable permanently. If I reopen a document where I disabled them, most of the times they just show up again. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: This related question/answer seems to fix this problem: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213395/9190

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!!! I cannot believe they chose to force us to use thumbnails with no option to take them away.