# Can I set Hide Sidebar as default in Preview

Tags: macos, preview

`Preview` has become rather annoying. I found a post to Hide Sidebar https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213395/19086

Even worse, if I select `Full Screen` mode I get Sidebar plus 2 pages side by side (which actually makes the document smaller and harder to read). Can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Full Screen you can hide the sidebar by unselecting View>Always Show Sidebar (shortcut <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>):

[image]

To get rid of the side by side view you need to select View>Single Page (shortcut <kbd>commmand</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>) instead of View>Two Pages:

[image]
[image]