# How to remove the sidebar in Apple Preview (presentation mode)?

Tags: preview, menu-bar, sidebar

Preview suddenly displays a sidebar on the left-hand side in presentation mode. I do not know how to disable this.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214206) mentions

```
Always Show Sidebar
```

in the `View` menu, but this does not seem to exist in Preview version 10.0.

**Update**

Even in full screen mode, I do not find this item in the `View` menu. This is what I see:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Preview version 10 and under my View menu there is an option to Hide sidebar. Doesn't it appear on your machine?

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question with what I see when I click `View` in full-screen mode. It seems that Hide Sidebar is grey, so I cannot (un)select it.

Comment: Can you select it before going to full-screen mode?

Comment: Yes, I can select `Hide Sidebar` (or `Thumbnails` or an other option) under the `View` menu before going to full-screen mode. In either case, it seems that I do not see the sidebar anymore now when going to full-screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

While Preview is in full screen, the option is available from the View menu and toolbar button.
The app **must be in full screen** for these to be available.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not see `Always Show Sidebar` when the app is in full screen, see my updated question.